# Emberjs: strange bug on iPhone

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember app that works very well on desktop (all major browsers), but it exhibits a strange bug on iPhone (and maybe Android as well, I am not sure).

It happens completely randomly, and even "worse": for some reason I can't replicate it when I connect my iPhone to my computer to use the Web Inspector. So basically I have no idea what's happening.

The app loads fine, but the bug occurs when the user transitions from one page to the other. This transition involves a bit of javascript and ajax (but not a super heavy script), and probably uses a bit of memory.

I apologize I know it is a long shot considering the little amount of info I have, but I was wondering whether someone has been confronted to something like that already? Or do you have any tips on how to track down a problem like this?

Thanks

PJ

Comment: you statet *This transition involves a bit of javascript and ajax (but not a super heavy script), and probably uses a bit of memory.* can you show code? without code it will be diffucult if not impossible to help you out...

Comment: I know... but the problem is I don't even exactly know "when" it happens - so it could be in many different places in the code. There is a router transition (transitionTo) but there are many other moving parts. And I don't think it's a bug in the code itself since it works well in all other browsers. So I was just hoping that - maybe - other people saw something similar and there are "known issues" on mobile Safari with Ember.

Comment: and what's the bug? how is your app reacting so that you can tell it's a bug? sorry, but with "something is wrong" withouth further explanation and/or code it's really hard if not _impossible_ to give you proper help...

Comment: Guys I really appreciate your help and I am sorry my question does not provide enough details - I simply don't have any. As you know there is no console on iPhone unless you connect it to a computer which makes it really hard to debug. I know there is a bug simply because the view is not rendered properly. But again: the bug could be anywhere before the rendering. It was a stab in the dark but I thought maybe someone on SO had also come across a weird behaviour on mobile safari. I will keep investigating and report back here if I find something.